# How to use relative path in Angular Google Maps directives?

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angularjs-directive, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to set a custom marker on an AngularJS Google Map:

```
<google-map
    draggable="true"
    style="display:block; width: 100%; height:100%;">
  <markers>
    <marker ng-repeat="marker in markers" coords="marker" icon="../img/marker-map.png">
    </marker>
  </markers>
</google-map>
```

This code throws the following error:

`Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression [../img/marker-map.png] starting at [../img/marker-map.png].`

On the [Angular Google Maps API documentation](http://angular-google-maps.org/api#marker), in Marker directive's `icon` parameter , it says:

> Expression returning the absolute path to an image used as the marker
>   icon

I think I misunderstood that statement. Isn't it possible to set a relative path for the marker icon image, as in the code example above? What could be an expression to reference the marker image?

Answer (score 2):

I got it, on the marker directive's icon parameter I should use a variable that references the marker image.

HTML:

```
<marker ng-repeat="marker in markers" coords="marker" icon="markerIcon">
</marker>
```

On my controller:

```
$scope.markerIcon = "img/marker-map.png";
```