# Local image for marker icon on Cordova/Phonegap Google Maps Plugin

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, phonegap-gmaps-plugin

Is it possible to use an image locally store on the device as the marker icon? I can use a URL and it works, but when I try to use a local image it won't load. How should I reference the image? This is a multiplatform application so I can't use device specific paths like Android `file:///android:asset/`

```
map.addMarker({
    'position': new plugin.google.maps.LatLng(13.7579507,100.5643353),
    'title': 'Fortune Town',
    'icon': '../templates/icon2.png'
}, function(marker) {
    marker.showInfoWindow();
});
```

I am using [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/) (which uses [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/)) and [Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) with the [Google Maps plugin from https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/](https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/)

Comment: `icon:'templates/icon2.png'` may be this will help

Comment: Thanks but I already tried many different paths :-( This is in the www/js and the icon is in www/templates, that's the reason for the '..', it should be like this, shouldn't it?

Comment: just add `'icon': 'icon2.png'`

Comment: Tried but no luck :-(

Comment: Try this link----http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24144265/how-to-use-relative-path-in-angular-google-maps-directives

Comment: I think Markers should be added after map is loaded.

Comment: Thanks @prabhu The marker loads fine, it's just the local image that won't load (will show default icon). The link is interesting but doesn't apply because I am not using the the HTML based map, all my map code is in the controller and nothing on the HTML.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It doesn't make too much sense but this is what worked:

```
'icon': 'www/templates/icon2.png'
```

Comment: Hi momo, thank you for using my plugin. Yes, this is correct answer for this plugin.
https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/wiki/Marker#simple-icon

Comment: Hey, thanks to you for writing the plugin, Katsumata :-) I could use a longer documentation though ;-P

Answer (score 0):

Use a storage plugin, like Cordova Storage, and pull it from there, or a local database.  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html
[Capturing and storing a picture taken with the Camera into a local database / PhoneGap / Cordova / iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335563/capturing-and-storing-a-picture-taken-with-the-camera-into-a-local-database-ph)